# How to make a 301 redirect in Zend Frameork 2?

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I need to make a redirect like this in ZF2:

```
redirect 301 /something /anotherway
```

I already have tried this on my `.htaccess` file, but that doesn't work in ZF2.

How can I do it? Thanks

Edited:

I have a lot of old urls to redirect of the old site on htaccess... Examples:

```
redirect 301 /something /anotherway
redirect 301 /something2 /anotherway2
redirect 301 /something3 /anotherway3
redirect 301 /something4 /anotherway4
redirect 301 /something5 /anotherway5
redirect 301 /something6 /anotherway6
```

If i put this on my .htaccess with ZF2, it does erros to me... How can i do it in ZF2?

Comment: Do you need to redirect to a route with status code of the response set to 301?

Comment: i need to redirect an Old Url to a New url, obs: I have a lot of links

Comment: I jus can't understand what you need. Your question is unclear, please add more details so that we could hep you

Answer (score 6):

From the controller

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl('http://where you want the redirect to go')->setStatusCode(301);
```

Comment: Hello Finbarr... my problem is: i have a lot of old links that i need to make this redirect to a new Url, something lke:

redirect 301 /something /anotherway
redirect 301 /something2 /anotherway2
redirect 301 /something3 /anotherway3

Comment: I like Finbarr's suggestion. You could make a dedicated Redirector controller, and define all your old routes to call it. I would use `toRoute` helper though, if the redirects are routes in your app.

Comment: Hi Marco I have just tested your own redirect (ie "Redirect 301 /something /anotherway" in /Public/.htaccess and it works fine on ZF2 - can you post the contents of your .htaccess file - the one I used is the standard from the skeleton application https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess